# Connect Huawei E3131B 3g Modem

Tags: usb, angstrom, 3g

I am attempting to connect a Huawei E3131B 3g modem using Linux. I use usb-modeswitch and pppd.

First I mode-switch the modem using the command:

```
usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1:14fe -v 12d1 -p 14fe
```

(12d1:14fe) is the address of the modem. This creates the /dev/ttyUSB0, 1 and 2 ports that can be used to communicate serially with the modem. Next, I run pppd with the following options:

```
debug
modem
/dev/ttyUSB0
460800
crtscts
lock
-detach
noipdefault
defaultroute
dump
noauth
connect '/usr/sbin/chat -v -t 60 -f /etc/ppp/chat-isp'
:
```

The connection script, chat-isp, looks as follows:

```
ABORT 'BUSY'
ABORT 'NO CARRIER'
''      ATI
OK      AT+CRSM=176,65507,0,0,17
OK      AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"
OK      ATQ0 V1 E1
OK      AT+CPIN="0000"
OK      AT+COPS=0,2
OK      AT+FCLASS=0
OK      AT+S0=0
OK      AT&D2&C1
OK      ATD*99#
CONNECT ""
ogin:
sword:
```

I'm going to be honest and say some of those AT commands are there plainly to try to get this thing to work! Can someone please help by telling me what is wrong with the connection script and what order / what AT functions need to be used to set up the modem?

Comment: What Linux distro are you using? Kernel version? Have you tried to use [ModemManager](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ModemManager/)?

Comment: I'm using Angstrom. And I've tried using ModemManager, but can't get it to work. The reason why I just want to use pppd is for speed reasons.

Comment: This [blog post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=18996) looks very interesting. I think in cdc_ether mode you'll get speed/bandwidth out of your modem.

Comment: Can you do `minicom /dev/ttyUSB0`? does it respond? does it give any output if you did `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` and waited for few seconds (in case you did not have minicom). Try using `ttyUSB2` and `ttyUSB1` instead.

Comment: @aularon. Yes, I can speak serially to the modem via ttyUSB0, when I try to perform the commands above, I get a response of CONNECT after I dial, but then it freezes...

Comment: I have Huawei e1550 and 1750, they both work (Ubuntu 12.04) with the following `.wvdial.conf`: https://gist.github.com/aularon/8804617